# bash + sed: trim trailing zeroes off a floating point number?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, floating-point

I'm trying to get trim off trailing decimal zeroes off a floating point number, but no luck so far.

```
echo "3/2" | bc -l | sed s/0\{1,\}\$//
1.50000000000000000000
```

I was hoping to get `1.5` but somehow the trailing zeroes are not truncated. If instead of `0\{1,\}` I explicitly write 0 or 000000 etc, it chops off the zeroes as entered, but obviously I need it to be dynamic.

What's wrong with `0\{1,\}` ?

Comment: Presumably this is a test case, otherwise you could change the `scale` parameter in `bc` to reduce the number of decimal places.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
echo "3/2" | bc -l | sed '/\./ s/\.\{0,1\}0\{1,\}$//'
```

- remove trailing 0 IF there is a decimal separator
- remove the separator if there are only 0 after separator also (assuming there is at least a digit before like BC does)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I didn't cover the exception yet to only remove zeroes after separator (I wouldn't want 3500 to be trimmed to 35) or removal of the separator itself if applicable. Wanted to wrap my head around getting the regex to work at all in the first place :) But great addition, thx!

Comment: Actually, I don't fully understand the first part of the sed parameter. Being a sed noob, I'm only familiar with sed using `s/<searchpattern>/<replacepattern>/`. Looking thru man sed, I understand the dot before the s is an 'address', which behaves as an extra filter, i.e. `sed /<filter>/s/<search>/<replace>/` will only replace `search` with `replace` for input that also matches `filter`, is that correct?

Comment: `/\./`is a pattern filter on line that contain a dot in it (avoiding to remove trailing 0 on a multiple of 10 like 25000). Filter, activate following action (or group if a `{}` is used ) only when pattern (or address) of the filter is compliant. So yes, you are correct

Answer (score 12):

Why don't you just set the number of digits you want with `scale`?

```
$ echo "scale=1; 3/2" | bc -l 
1.5
$ echo "scale=2; 3/2" | bc -l 
1.50
$ echo "scale=5; 3/2" | bc -l 
1.50000
```

I recommend you to go through `man bc`, since it contains many interesting ways to present your result.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into `man bc` as it's quite new to me. However in this particular case, I don't want a specific number of digits, but rather maximum precision and just ditch any unnecessary trailing zeroes.

Comment: Trailing zeros *are* necessary for maximum precision. `1.5000` is far more precise than `1.5` (which may be anything between `1.45` and `1.54`.

Comment: it does not reply to question but do the request behind .  Let assume that in your reply in case of `bc -l` is just the sample generator (you still get my vote)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu yep, I was going to the core of the problem instead of the `sed` problem the OP found in his workaround. However, to me the best way to control the format is by using `printf`, like [Pedro Lobito's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30046145/1983854) shows.

Comment: @chepner I agree that in general `1.5000` is different (more precise) than `1.5`, but in this particular case I want to get rid of remaining zeroes.

Answer (score 6):

`$` must not be escaped and quote sed pattern:

```
echo "3/2" | bc -l | sed 's/0\{1,\}$//'
1.5
```

Comment: @Etan actually, the `\{1,\}` [is the more portable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06)

Answer (score 2):

@anubhava has the right reason for your failed command, but just use awk instead:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print 3/2}'
1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf` for that:

```
printf "%.1f" $(bc -l <<< '3/2')
1.5
```

Comment: good one! I thought about using `printf` but failed to make it work, since I was using `printf "%f" $(( 3/2 ))` and `$(( ))` just does int arithmetic.

Comment: That will round every result to 1 decimal place, not strip off trailing zeros as the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

One of the handy way to trim off trailing zeroes of a *floating* number is 
`grep --only-matching` option:

```
$ echo 1 + 0.1340000010202010000012301000000000 | bc -l | grep -o '.*[1-9]'
1.1340000010202010000012301
```

> -o, --only-matching
>
> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each
>   such part on a separate output line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take. It removes leading zeros, and then if there is a decimal anywhere in the number, it also removes trailing zeros. This expression also works for numbers preceded or followed by space characters if present.

```
sed -e "s/^\s*0*//" -e "/\./ s/0*\s*$//"
```